# Maven resources files not in build JAR (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, executable-jar

I'm using Maven for the first time (so I'm a beginner) to build a Client/Server Uni java project (named Climate Monitoring) using IntelliJ and I would like to get two executable JAR file one for the Client and one for the Server.

[My Maven Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80i83.png)

[This is my pom.xml 'profile' section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNDc3.png)

I used profiles to be able to build the client and server separately, my problem right now is that when I build the Server and launch the JAR the server can't find the DBConfig.config file that it needs to read from the resources files.
Inside the code I have a DbManager class that needs to read from the DBConfig.config file in the resources folder and I use `DbManager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config/DBconfig.config")` to get the InputStream.
Also i checked inside the JAR and there is no DBConfig.config file or any file in the resources folder, these are only placed in the /target/classes folder and not in the executable JAR which is in the /target folder.

I can't change the project folder structure (for reason that I won't explain here) so if you can help me find a solution for this problem I would be grateful.

Comment: Try `DbManager.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/DBconfig.config");` You won't ever see a 'folder' called 'resources' in the jar. It should be config at its root

Comment: Post text rather than images, wherever practical.

Comment: I am no Maven maven, but my understanding is that if you want your project to produce multiple artifacts, you should employ the [multi-module](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=maven%20multi-module%20project&tts=st_asaf_macos) feature in Maven. Each Maven module within your project produces one artifact. (Not to be confused with [*Java Platform Module System (JPMS)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System))

Comment: thanks for the answers:
@g00se i tried it , it didn't work, same problem

Comment: @BasilBourque that was what i did but stack overflow flagged it as spam and didn't let me post it

Comment: Please post your pom *formatted as code*. That should have been done in the first place
*... but stack overflow flagged it as spam ...* On the contrary. It's only flagged as spam when links are posted instead of formatted text